# My python list comprehension fails due to a syntax error

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

Python noob using version 3.2.3...

```
class Card:
    def __init__(self, suitID, rank):
            self.suits = ("Spades", "Hearts", "Diamonds","Clubs")
            self.rank = rank
            self.suit = self.suits[suitID]

    def __str__(self):
            return (str("%s of %s" % (self.rank, self.suit)))


class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
            self.cards = [Card(i//13, i%13) for i in range(52)]
```

The above is how I have things set up, seems fine to me. The confusion is in the following (please ignore the **return ("")** statement as this is only for testing)

**Case 1:**

```
def __str__(self):
    print ( self.cards [i for i in range (52) ] )
    return("")
```

**Output:**

```
File "cardgame.py", line 21
print (self.cards[i for i in range(52)])
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Why the error? I thought that was how LC's were used...

---

**Case 2:**

```
def __str__(self):
    print (myCards for myCards in self.cards)
return ("")
```

**Output:**

```
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x2256fa0>
```

Again, what does that mean, and why does it not output the data?

---

**Case 3:**

```
def __str__(self):
    for myCard in self.cards:
          print (myCard)
    return ("")
```

**Output:**

```
0 of Spades
1 of Spades
2 of Spades
3 of Spades
4 of Spades
...
..
.
```

Now this outputs exactly what I want, but that confuses me ever more. I was under the impression that all three cases are equivalent and they are clearly not. What are the differences?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Gives me a huge list of addresses like:[<__main__.Card object at 0x1d0c310>, <__main__.Card object at 0x1d0c350>, <__main__.Card object at 0x1d0c390>, <__main__.Card object at 0x1d0c3d0>, <__main__.Car..............

Comment: Please ask one question per question.

Answer (score 1):

Case 1:

You should pass an integer rather than `i for i in range (52)` as the index of a list. Try `print [self.cards[i] for i in range(52)]`. And you can just write `print self.cards` if there are only 52 cards in `self.cards`.

Case 2 & Case 3:

`(myCards for myCards in self.cards)` is a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) in Python. You can iterate it like a list in Case 3, but it will not return all its elements at first, which is an important feature of generators.

Comment: I understood your first point, but not the one about generators. Also `print (self.cards)` gives me a list like: `[<__main__.Card object at 0x1d0c310>, <__main__.Card object at 0x1d0c350>, <__main__.Card object at 0x1d0c390>, <__main__.Card object at 0x1d0c3d0>, <__main__.Card object at 0x1d0c410>, <__main__.Ca....`

Comment: @Deedaus You can only get a generator when there is a comprehension like `i for i in range(52)` inside brackets rather than just `self.cards`.

Answer (score 1):

The is is List Comprehensions, you'd better to learn it's gramar.

> li = [1,2,3]
>
> la = [i for i in li] # the la is a list [1,2,3]
>
> lb = (i for i in li) # lb is a generator object, and list(lb) is [1,2,3]

in case 1, `print [self.cars[i] for i in range(52)]` will work.

in your code `(self.cars[i for i in range(52)])`, the `[i for i in range(52)]` is a list,so `self.cars[list objeject]` is invalid.

Comment: Ahhh I am starting to get it a little...Thanks mate

Answer (score 1):

`print (self.cards[i for i in range(52)])`

You are trying to use a list to index into a list. This is like doing the following:

```
>>> l = [4,5,6]
>>> l[i for i in range (3)]
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    l[i for i in range (3)]
```

Answer (score 1):

For your first case, that is not how you arrange Python syntax.

```
print(self.cards[i for i in range (52)])
```

You are indexing a `list` with another `list`. It doesn't make any sense. What you probably meant to do was this:

```
print([self.cards[i] for i in range(52)])
```

Note that this just creates a new `list`. The expression `[self.cards[i] for i in range(52)]`, operating on a `list` with 52 elements, has the same result as `self.cards`. You are adding unnecessary stuff and going in circles.

For your second case, this:

```
print(myCards for myCards in self.cards)
```

is printing a generator expression, which is represented as:

```
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x2256fa0>
```

For your third case, which prints *each item in that object* rather than printing the object itself, you can unpack your generator expression above with `*` and specify a custom separator:

```
print(*(myCards for myCards in self.cards), sep='\n')
```

Of course, note that you are once again copying that `list` for no reason. Just use the original one instead of spending time and effort (both yours and the computer's) making a new one.

```
print(*myCards, sep='\n')
```